# Namespaced controller without having to name space route helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Is it possible to reference `app/controllers/admin/categories_controller.rb` using `categories_path` instead of `admin_categories_path` ?

I'm using Rails 4.

```
# app/controllers/admin
class Admin::CategoriesController < Admin::BaseController
end

# visiting localhost:3000/admin/categories causes route not found error 'admin/categories'
scope module: "admin" do
  resources :categories
end

# visiting localhost:3000/admin/categories causes uninitialized constant CategoriesController
scope "/admin" do
  resources :categories
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that you have to reference the controller at the resources

```
scope 'admin' do
  resources :categories, controller: 'admin/categories'
end
```

so the routes became

```
   categories   GET    /admin/categories(.:format)          admin/categories#index
                POST   /admin/categories(.:format)          admin/categories#create
   new_category GET    /admin/categories/new(.:format)      admin/categories#new
  edit_category GET    /admin/categories/:id/edit(.:format) admin/categories#edit
       category GET    /admin/categories/:id(.:format)      admin/categories#show
                PATCH  /admin/categories/:id(.:format)      admin/categories#update
                PUT    /admin/categories/:id(.:format)      admin/categories#update
                DELETE /admin/categories/:id(.:format)      admin/categories#destroy
```